# carrierwave: reject .gif renamed to .jpg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, rmagick

I would like to allow users to upload `.jpg` files but only if they are actually `.jpg` (e.g.,  `cat.gif` renamed to `cat.jpg` would **not** work.

Currently in my Carrierwave `ImageUploader.rb` I have:

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
process :set_content_type
def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg png)
end
```

and in my Rspec test file I test it three ways:

```
# Works
describe "with invalid mime type and invalid extension" do
  before do
    image.image = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'image', 'images', 'executable.jpg')) # this is a .exe renamed to .jpg
  end
  it { image.should_not be_valid }
end

# Works
describe "with invalid mime type and invalid extension" do
  before do
    image.image = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'image', 'images', 'test_gif.gif')) # this is a .gif
  end
  it { should_not be_valid }
end

# Doesn't work
describe "with invalid mime type and valid extension" do
  before do
    image.image = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'image', 'images', 'test_gif.jpg')) # this is a .gif renamed to .jpg
  end
  it { image.should_not be_valid }
end
```

The tests pass for the first two, but fail on the second. I'm not sure why, since I don't have `gif` on the whitelist and I'm checking the mime types.

Any suggestions?

(Converting gifs to jpgs is my backup, but I would rather just deny them.)

Comment: I think extension_white_list only checks the extension. I think you need to actually check the content_type attribute: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Store-the-uploaded-file-size-and-content-type

Comment: the second "describe" is "it { should_not be_valid }" and others are "it { image.should_not  ...  " 
are you sure the second "it" is the subject?

Comment: @micapam by including MimeTypes I was under impression that I was checking content_type: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#setting-the-content-type

Comment: @kukrt double checked, the subject was image on all of the other ones as well

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and had to override the default set_content_type method for my uploader. This assumes you have **Rmagick** gem in your Gemfile, so that you can get the correct mime-type from reading the image, as opposed to making a best guess.

Note: This is particularly useful if the image is being used by Prawn which supports only JPG and PNG images.

**Uploader Class:**

```
process :set_content_type

def set_content_type #Note we are overriding the default set_content_type_method for this uploader
  real_content_type = Magick::Image::read(file.path).first.mime_type
  if file.respond_to?(:content_type=)
    file.content_type = real_content_type
  else
    file.instance_variable_set(:@content_type, real_content_type)
  end
end
```

**Image Model:**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of :image
  validate :validate_content_type_correctly

  before_validation :update_image_attributes

private
  def update_image_attributes
    if image.present? && image_changed?
      self.content_type = image.file.content_type
    end
  end

  def validate_content_type_correctly
    if not ['image/png', 'image/jpg'].include?(content_type)
      errors.add_to_base "Image format is not a valid JPEG or PNG."
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```